# Does clang already support C++11?

Tags: c++, clang, c++11

I would like to use `std::array`, `std::regex` and other things that are new in C++11.

Does clang already support C++11?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes but not everything. Check out this [status page](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html); it's updated very frequently. It's the current source code (work in progress) state, not the last release state, so check the version in the table to be sure it corresponds to what you have.

For standard library features, checks the links at the end of the page, depending on which context you are in.

Also, the Apache wiki includes [this table](https://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport) summarizing C++11 features and their support in popular compilers.

Comment: Important note: this is the status of the current top of the tree.

Answer (score 4):

The parts of C++11 that you're looking for are actually part of the standard library. If you're using the clang compiler, you'll want to use the [libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org/) standard library, which has support for most of C++11 and works really well with clang.

Comment: Excepting possibly C++11 language features used *inside* the C++11 library such as constexpr, nullptr, initializer lists, rvalue refs.  That's one of the reasons each version of libstdc++ is coupled so tightly to the corresponding version of gcc.

Comment: They're part of the _C++ Standard Library_, **not** part of the STL.